# how to write test cases in clojure

Tags: clojure

i am beginner in clojure 
I wrote

```
(expect true (valid? "henry" "as@gmail.com" "9999999999" "tesxt message"))
```

in my `(ns clojuregeek.test.contact)`

when i run the test cases by lein test in clojure i found:--

```
lein test clojuregeek.test.contact

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

failure in (contact.clj:32) : clojuregeek.test.contact
(expect
 true
 (valid? "henry" "as@gmail.com" "9999999999" "tesxt message"))

  act-msg: exception in actual: (valid? "henry" "as@gmail.com" "9999999999" "tesxt message")
    threw: class java.lang.ClassCastException - clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Future
           noir.validation$get_errors$doInvoke (validation.clj:94)
           noir.validation$errors_QMARK_$doInvoke (validation.clj:140)
           on (contact.clj:34)
           on (contact.clj:32)

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions in 178 msecs
0 failures, 1 errors.
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://yogthos.net/blog/46

Comment: A lot of lib-noir didn't work unless you wrap your code in the with-noir macro. Your error message tells me this is a noir problem, not a test problem.

Answer (score 2):

While developing a petri net simulator in Clojure, the testing environment **Midje** was the best choice to write useful and simple testcases. Maybe you just take a look at this...

Testcases are really simple. You just create your facts in `test/core_tests.clj` like:

```
(ns your-namespace.core-tests
  (:use midje.sweet)
   :require [your-namespace.core :as core])

(fact "Testing valid?"
  (core/valid? "henry" "as@gmail.com" "9999999999" "tesxt message") => true)

;; some more facts...
```

For preparation you need to modify your `project.clj`:

```
(defproject your-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description ""
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME";TODO
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [midje "1.6.2"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot your-project.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}
             :dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.6.2"]]
                   :plugins [[lein-midje "3.1.3"]]}})
```

After this you can start a new terminal window and type in your project folder first `lein deps` and after this:

```
lein midje :autotest
```

and Midje is going to run through your test every time you save a file in your project folder.

In my opinion one of the best solutions to write simple and useful testcases.